# Java : Unable to get Long value from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to get my Long value under the name "WeeklyDate" to convert into a Date value but when I try referencing the Long value, it keeps returning a null error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference

This is my current line:

```
weeklyDate = snapshot.child("WeeklyDate").getValue(Long.class);
```

Reference Line:

```
Date storedDate = new Date(weeklyDate);
```

Ive tried Instatianting the weeklyDate at the top of the class by doing:

`Long weeklyDate = 0L;` and `Long weeklyDate = new Long(1);` The null error is gone, but the value is still wrong I've checked.

Here is the entire section of the code:

```
public class HomeParentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeParentViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<HomeParentData> data;
    Context c;
    Integer random;

    HomeMixData weekly_post = new HomeMixData();

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    String weeklyPost;
    Long weeklyDate = new Long(1);

    public HomeParentAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HomeParentData> data){
        this.data = data;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    //getting position of viewholder, if its 0, return 0 else return 1
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == 0)?0:1;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HomeParentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Setting layout file and doing rv of nested layout within parent RV if posiiton of viewholder == 0
        View item;
        HomeMix homeMix = new HomeMix();
        if (viewType == 0){
            //Inflating child layout within Parent RV
            item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.activity_home_child, null, false);

            // Making Child RV for child layout within parent RV
            ArrayList<HomeChildData> data = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<HomeMixData> sortedMixList = homeMix.filterDT();
            ArrayList<HomeMixData> randomMixList = homeMix.RandomData();

            ImageView weekly_img = item.findViewById(R.id.weekly_img);
            TextView weekly_title = item.findViewById(R.id.weekly_title);
            TextView weekly_author = item.findViewById(R.id.weekly_author);


            // Getting WEEKLY date & post ID Values From Database
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
//                    Getting Weekly Items from database
                    weeklyDate = snapshot.child("WeeklyDate").getValue(Long.class);
                    weeklyPost = snapshot.child("WeeklyPost").getValue(String.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

            if (randomMixList.size() > 0){
                // post to retrieve for weekly feature determines randomly
                final int random = new Random().nextInt(randomMixList.size());
                ArrayList<HomeMixData> weekly_list = new ArrayList<>();
                weekly_post = randomMixList.get(random);

                //Getting Current Date Week
                Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
                calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
                calendar.setTime(currentDate);
                int currentWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                Log.e("Week", "Current"+currentWeek);

                //Getting Stored Date Week
                Date storedDate = new Date(weeklyDate);
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(storedDate);
                int storedWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                Log.e("Week", "Stored"+storedWeek);

                if (currentWeek != storedWeek){ // setting post and date if post has not been updated this week
                    homeMix.setWeekly(weekly_post);
                    Log.e("beef", "false");
                }
                else{ // getting post from databse, if this week has been updated
                    for(HomeMixData i : randomMixList){
                        if (i.postID == weeklyPost){ // getting the object that matches the ID
                            weekly_post = i;
                            Log.e("beef", "true");
                        }
                    }
                }

                weekly_list.add(weekly_post); // can be passed to bundle
                //Setting items of things in Weekly post using sortedMixList
                if (weekly_post.identifier == true) { // if its Hawker Corner post
                    weekly_title.setText(weekly_post.hcstallname);
                    weekly_author.setText("By: "+weekly_post.hcauthor);
                    Picasso.get().load(weekly_post.hccoverimg).into(weekly_img);
                }
                else{// if its Recipe Corner post
                    weekly_title.setText(weekly_post.recipeName);
                    weekly_author.setText(weekly_post.userName);
                    Picasso.get().load(weekly_post.foodImage).into(weekly_img);
                }
```

Here is the Firebase information that I would like to retrieve:

```
{
  "WeeklyDate": 1655453785645,
  "WeeklyPost": "-N4h6xJSy_iC0WZ_2UjT"
}
```

This is how I stored it into FIrebase:

```
       public void setWeekly(HomeMixData data) {
        Long weeklyDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String weeklyPostUID = data.postID;

        // Put object into Firebase
        databaseReferencetest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseReferencetest.child("WeeklyDate").setValue(weeklyDate);
        databaseReferencetest.child("WeeklyPost").setValue(weeklyPostUID);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `getValue(Long.class)` is returning null.  You're going to have to do some debugging to figure out why that is - we can't see based on the little you've shown here.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Besides that, please also add the entire code that you're using for reading the data.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added more code that I used, but I couldn't figure out how to add the JSON file in stack overflow so I attached an image.

Comment: Have you tried to get the schema as mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I've just edited and added the JSON code that I've exported. I hope that is what you're looking for.

Comment: We need to see your structure, not only those values.

Comment: Maybe there are some limitation according long values?

Comment: @AlexMamo Currently, "WeeklyDate" and "WeeklyPost" are the only data in my firebase.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand. You only have two values in your database, and you want to display them into a RecycerView using an adapter?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, as it is a nested recycler view, for a layout file. I've managed to fix the issue, thanks a lot for your help I was close to giving up, but the problem was not with Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive managed to fix the issue after some troubleshooting.

I just had to instantiate a date value Date storedDate = new Date();
and convert Long into a Date value directly after grabbing it from firebase. That fixed my null error as well.